# Generate the type-definition for the polkadot.js apps

Tags: custom-rpc, apps

Currently, I am trying to add the custom RPC into the polkadot.js apps to let me send the RPC call via polkadot.js apps.

I discovered that I have to generate my type-definition with the RPC/types, a file in the `apps/packages/apps-config/src/api/spec`, and set it up in the `apps/packages/apps-config/src/api/spec/index.ts`.

However, there are several projects (`acala.js/packages/type-definitions`, `sora2-substrate-js-library/packages/type-definitions`) that define their type-definitions. After I define my type-definition like them, how could I use these files to convert to the files which the apps-config in apps can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way. I should use the [script](https://github.com/polkadot-js/dev/blob/master/packages/dev/package.json#L23), `polkadot-dev-build-ts`, to convert them to the files that polkadot.js/apps are needed.

Comment: Can you explain how did you use it? facing the same issue, I've generated the types using `typegen` and now I want them to use in the `polkadot-js/apps`